# How to remove all soft hyphens (U+00AD) from a file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, unicode

There is a thing called [Soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen). Its unicode value is `U+00AD` and it cannot be seen in my text editor.

Apparently, a few of my files are riddled with it:

```
$ perl -C7 -ne 'for(split(//)){print sprintf("U+%04X", ord)." ".$_."\n"}'
n­c
U+006E n
U+00AD ­
U+0063 c
U+000A
```

In between `n` and `c`, there is a soft hyphen. If you copy this command `echo n­c`, you will find that it has three characters (not two).

How can I remove all soft hyphens (U+00AD) from my file?

Comment: What is the `ord` in your `sprintf()` command?

Comment: @terdon `ord()` is the Perl function that returns the ASCII code for a given character. It acts on `$_` in the code in the question. The value in `$_`  is one of the elements of the result of `split(//)`. The call to `split()` turns the input into a list of separate characters.

Comment: Ah! It was a function! Thanks, @they, the lack of `()` threw me, stupidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sed` (I tested with GNU `sed`, I do not know if non-GNU seds can do it) and copy/paste the character into the sed expression. Here, I copied your `echo n­c` command and ran it, redirecting the output to a file which gave me a test file with the character of interest:

```
$ perl -C7 -ne 'for(split(//)){print sprintf("U+%04X", ord)." ".$_."\n"}' file
U+006E n
U+00C2 Â
U+00AD ­
U+0063 c
U+000A
```

It also added a `U+00C2 Â` which I don't understand but I don't know unicode, so I assume it's some sort of unicode weirdness. The file looks as expected, there is actually what appears like a space but is in fact the soft hyphen between the `a` and `n`:

```
$ cat file
n­c

$ od -c file
0000000   n 302 255   c  \n
0000005
```

Regardless, copy/pasting that apparently white space and feeding it to `uniprops`, gives:

```
$ uniprops '­'
U+00AD ‹U+00AD› \N{SOFT HYPHEN}
    \pC \p{Cf}
    All Any Assigned C Other Case_Ignorable CI Cf Format Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded CWKCF Common Zyyy Default_Ignorable_Code_Point DI Graph X_POSIX_Graph
       Latin_1 Latin_1_Supplement Latin_1_Sup InLatin1 Print X_POSIX_Print Unicode
```

And copying into a `sed` substitution operator gives:

```
$ sed 's/­//g' file | perl -C7 -ne 'for(split(//)){print sprintf("U+%04X", ord)." ".$_."\n"}'
U+006E n
U+0063 c
U+000A
```

In other words, it correctly removes it. So you can apply that command to all of the affected files:

```
sed -i 's/­//g' file1 file2 ... fileN
```

Try it on a couple of files first (and use `-i.bak` or `i .bak` depending on your OS and sed implementation to keep a backup to test safely) and then run it on all of them.

Comment: Or just `tr -d '\302\255'` (portable).

Comment: `echo C­A | sed 's/\xc2\xad//g'` given in [How to replace Unicode characters with ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052194/how-to-replace-unicode-characters-with-ascii/27056408#27056408) and `echo C­A | sed $'s/\u00AD//g'` given in [bash-replacing a number with unicode character using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140408/bash-replacing-a-number-with-unicode-character-using-sed/27141959#27141959) both also worked for me.

Comment: @Quasímodo that could be a useful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's:g/\c[SOFT HYPHEN]//;' file
```

Raku provides high-level Unicode support, built-in. No need to load libraries or remember command line flags. Above utilizes one way identifying Unicode characters in Raku, `\c[SOFT HYPHEN]`, i.e. just spell out the name! Or you could use the Unicode identifier:

```perl
raku -pe 's:g/\x00AD//;' file
```

Two things about Raku's version of the familiar `s///` substitution operator: you place modifiers like `:global` (known as 'adverbs' in Raku) immediately after the `s`, as in `s:global` or its abbreviation, `s:g`.

Secondly, a less 'backslashy` version of the above code is as follows:

```perl
raku -pe 's:g[\c[SOFT HYPHEN]]="";' file
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's:g[\x00AD]="";' file
```

See the links for discussion of Raku's Unicode support.

https://www.codesections.com/blog/raku-unicode/
https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode